# How to get a display in descending order

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know there is a simple answer to this question but I have searched for 2 days trying to find it. I have a program in rails that lists workers in the home building industry. I ask for the following informatio occupation, first name, second name,telephone number, email address. This information is displayed without any editing of my code. I would like to display this information using the order query and showing the information using the occupation column in descending order. Please tell me the code to use and where it goes.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a method named `index` inside your controller. Ok, inside the `index` method, you can use `.order` method.

Make it like this:

```
def index
    @users = User.order(occupation: :desc)
end
```

Reference:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order

Comment: Zuhl thanks for the information I can't believe that it was that easy you can't believe the hours I spent trying to figure this out. I just knew there had to be a lot more code added. You have just enabled me to complete the code for my entire web site. I need five different controllers and five different tables and all 5 are coded the same way with no linking between them. Thank  you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: @JerryLowery you're most welcome. Glad it works for you. Please do accept my answer. :)

Comment: You should accept the answer, Jerry, if it worked for you

Comment: yes it worked for me. it was just what I ask for. again thanks very much